# Binary Search tree problem

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I'm facing segmentation fault in this program. The flow seems to be correct as I figured out it to be. Please, help me find out the error in this program.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std; 

struct node 
{ 
    int data; 
    struct node* left; 
    struct node* right; 
}; 

typedef struct node* Node; 
void insert(Node,int); 
Node root = NULL; 
int main() 
{ 
    insert(root,2); 
    insert(root,1); 
    insert(root,3); 

    cout<<root->data<<" "<<root->left->data<<" "<<root->right->data<<endl; 
    return 0; 
} 

void insert(Node nod,int val) 
{ 
    if(nod == NULL) 
    {
        Node newnode = new(struct node); 
        newnode->data = val; 
        newnode->left = NULL; 
        newnode->right = NULL; 
        nod = newnode; 
        if(root == NULL) 
        { 
            root = newnode; 
        } 
    } 
    else if(nod->data > val) 
    { 
        insert(node->left,val); 
    } 
    else if(nod->data < val) 
    {  
        insert(nod->right,val); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing that actually sets `root->left` or `root->right`. The calls to `insert(node->left, val)` are not doing what you think it will do. In order to actually modify the left and right pointers, you need to pass the address of the pointers to insert. i.e. `insert(&node->left, val)`, and change `insert` to handle it.

Comment: yes, you can see it by looking to see whether node->left or node->right appear as L-values; the only thing they are ever set to is NULL, so you *know* this code isn't building a tree, as is apparently the intent.

Answer (score 0):

it is simple. Change your insert to:

```
void insert(Node &nod,int val) 
{ 
  if(nod == NULL) {

    Node newnode = new(struct node); 
    newnode->data = val; 
    newnode->left = NULL; 
    newnode->right = NULL; 
    nod = newnode; 
  } 
  else if(nod->data > val) 
    { 
      insert(nod->left,val); 
    } 
  else if(nod->data < val) 
    {  
      insert(nod->right,val); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: You should outline your changes rather than handing them a chunk of code.